# Memory use of Apply vs Map. Virtual memory use and lock-ups

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, memory-management

I needed to find the sum of all pairs of numbers in a long list of pairs. Lots of ways to do this in Mathematica, but I was thinking of using either `Plus` or `Total`. Since `Total` works on lists, `Map` is the functional programming instrument to use there and `Apply` at level 1 (@@@) is the one to use for `Plus`, as `Plus` takes the numbers to be added as arguments.

Here is some demo code (**warning**: save all your work before executing this!):

```
pairs = Tuples[Range[6000], {2}]; (* toy example *)

TimeConstrained[Plus @@@ pairs; // Timing, 30]

(* Out[4]= {21.73, Null} *)

Total /@ pairs; // Timing

(* Out[5]= {3.525, Null} *)
```

You might have noticed that I've added `TimeConstrained` to the code for `Plus`. This is a protective measure I included for you because the bare code brought my PC almost to its knees. In fact, the above code works for me, but if I increase the range in the first line to 7000 my computer just locks up and never gets back. Nothing works, no alt-period, program switching, ctrl-alt-delete, attempts to fire up the process manager using the taskbar, closing the laptop lid to let it sleep, etc., really nothing.

The problem is caused by the extreme memory use of the `Plus @@@ pairs` line. While 'pairs' itself takes up about 288 MB, and the list of totals half of that, the Plus line quickly consumes about 7 GB for its calculations. This is the end of my free physical memory and anything bigger causes the use of virtual memory on disk. And Mathematica and/or Windows apparently don't play nice when virtual memory is used (BTW, do MacOS and Linux behave better?). In contrast, the Total line doesn't have a noticeable impact on the memory usage graph.

I have two questions:

1. Given the equivalence between `Plus` and `Total` as stated in the documentation (*"Total[list] is equivalent to Apply[Plus,list]."* ) how to explain the extreme difference in behavior? I assume this has to do with the differences between `Apply` and `Map`, but I'm curious as to the internal mechanisms involved.
2. I know I can restrict the memory footprint of a command by using `MemoryConstrained`, but it is a pain to have to use this everywhere where you suspect Mathematica might usurp all of your system resources. Is there a global setting that I can use to tell Mathematica to use physical memory only (or, preferably, a certain fraction thereof) for all of its operations? This would be extremely helpful as this behavior has caused a handful of lockups the last couple of weeks and it's really starting to annoy me.

Comment: To whoever is trying out the above code: You might want to start with a much smaller list than the above. It nearly nuked my mac with 4GB memory (total, so free is much lesser).

Comment: @yoda TimeConstrained didn't get you out? It worked for me.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Nope. I guess it went from 0 to kaboom before `TimeConstrained` even realized what happend.

Comment: You've asked if the same thing happens in MacOS or Linux. I can't tell you for MacOS, but in Linux the same thing happens, as soon as you run it you get out of RAM (my 4Gb), swap kicks in, and then everything freezes till you kill the process (for which you need to wait till your commands get executed) or wait for it to finish (which I didn't).

Comment: It is probably tangential to the real question asked here, but the fastest way to perform the specific computation in question is likely to use `Total[pairs, {2}]`, which involves neither `Map` nor `Apply`.

Comment: @Leonid. Right on, it's about 5 times faster.

Comment: @Sjoerd I was wrong - `Plus @@ Transpose[pairs]` is even twice faster, which is IMO rather remarkable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just want to add a couple of observations that may clarify the situation a bit more. As noted in the answer by @Joshua (see also the comments to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449065/changing-values-in-nested-lists-according-to-elements-in-the-list/5449184#5449184) post for a similar discussion), the reason for inefficiency is related to unpacking. My guess is that the general reason why `Apply` unpacks is that the compiler (`Compile`) has a very limited support for `Apply` - namely, only 3 heads can be used - `List`, `Plus` and `Times`. For this reason, in the `SystemOptions["CompileOptions"]`, we can see that the compile length for `Apply` is set to infinity - it just does not make sense in general to even attempt auto-compiling `Apply`. And then probably, when the compilation length is larger than the real array dimension, it unpacks. When we set the `"ApplyCompileLength"` to a finite length, the behavior does change:

```
On["Packing"]
pairs=Tuples[Range[2000],{2}];
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions"->"ApplyCompileLength"->100];
TimeConstrained[Plus@@@pairs;//Timing,30]

{0.594,Null}
```

Changing it back again restores the observed initial behavior:

```
In[34]:= 
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "ApplyCompileLength" -> Infinity];
TimeConstrained[Plus @@@ pairs; // Timing, 30]

During evaluation of In[34]:= Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack1: Unpacking 
array with dimensions  {4000000,2}. >>

Out[35]= {2.094, Null}
```

Regarding your second question: perhaps, the systematic way to constrain the memory is along the lines of what @Alexey Popkov did, by using the master kernel to control the slave kernel that is restarted once the memory is low. I can offer a hack that is far less sophisticated but may still be of some use. The following function

```
ClearAll[totalMemoryConstrained];
SetAttributes[totalMemoryConstrained, HoldRest];
Module[{memException},
  totalMemoryConstrained[max_, body_, failexpr_] :=
   Catch[MemoryConstrained[body,
     Evaluate[
       If[# < 0, Throw[failexpr, memException], #] &@(max -
         MemoryInUse[])], failexpr], memException]];
```

will attempt to constrain the total memory used by the kernel, not just in a given particular computation. So, you can try wrapping it around your top-level function call, just once. Since it relies on `MemoryConstrained` and `MemoryInUse`, it is only as good as they are. More details on how it can be used, can be found in [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/bc41b4a5f51fbcb8) Mathgroup post. You can use `$Pre` to automate the application of this to your input, and reduce the amount of boilerplate code.

Comment: @Leonid In comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449065/changing-values-in-nested-lists-according-to-elements-in-the-list/5449184#5449184) you wrote that changing the setting of "ApplyCompileLength" to 100 does not speed up the `Apply`-based method. That case looks very similar to the case in this thread. What is the reason for the difference?

Comment: @Alexey Generically, it does not make sense to set "ApplyCompileLength" to a finite number, because there are just 3 heads for which this may matter (see my post). But here, we are dealing exactly with one of them - `Plus`.

Comment: @Leonid Now I understand. `Plus @@@ pairs` does not unpack while `Plus@# & @@@ pairs` unpacks. What is the reason for this limitation?

Comment: @Leonid Thoughtful answer, as always. I didn't find much documentation on those `"CompileOptions"`. Do you have access to additional documentation? totalMemoryConstrained works as advertised, but I don't manage to get it to work in $Pre ($Pre := totalMemoryConstrained[3000000000, #, Print["physical memory full"]] &). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Alexey My guess is that  `Apply` makes it possible to do things like run-time code generation etc, and is naturally much harder to compile than `Map`. `Map` (with a fixed level spec) can me mapped (pun unintended) to (nested) loop(s), and the structure of generated code can be easily predicted.  OTOH, `Apply` requires a low-level support for  functions with variable number of arguments, and more sophisticated type-inferencing is needed to determine their signatures at compile-time. Also, some functions like `Outer`, which can be used with `Apply`, are inherently hard to compile.

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks! No, I did not read any additional documentation. I think I was pointed to this once by someone or saw it in some post, and then did a few experiments. As for `$Pre`, you should hold the code, so this should work: `$Pre = Function[code, totalMemoryConstrained[300000000, code, 
   Print["physical memory full"]], HoldAll]`.

Comment: @Leonid That works. One caveat though: if you set the memory constraint too low and you bounce against the memory wall you can't change $Pre to another function or none at all, as $Pre itself is executed if you try to change it and hence it prevents that. Your value is one zero less than I used (300 MB instead of 3GB) and after the first run every command executed yielded the exception message.

Comment: @Sjoerd I see, indeed an inconvenience. A simple way out is to execute `Evaluate[$Pre =.]` (or, instead of `Unset`, put whatever you want as new `$Pre`, as the r.h.s. ). While we are at it, another note is that, unfortunately, `totalMemoryConstrained` does not prevent the allocator to temporarily allocate much more memory than we prescribe. So, I can easily imagine cases where it will not be very effective.

Answer (score 9):

`Plus@@@pairs` is unpacking:

```
In[11]:= On["Packing"]
In[12]:= pairs=Tuples[Range[6000],{2}];
In[13]:= TimeConstrained[Plus@@@pairs;//Timing,30]
During evaluation of In[13]:= Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack1: Unpacking array with dimensions {36000000,2}. >>
Out[13]= $Aborted
```

This will do the same thing and doesn't unpack, meaning it uses much less memory.

```
On["Packing"]
pairs=Tuples[Range[6000],{2}];
a = pairs[[All, 1]];b=pairs[[All, 2]];
Plus[a, b];
```

You can read more about packing in Mathematica here:
http://www.wolfram.com/technology/guide/PackedArrays/

Comment: but Total/@pairs also unpacks, so it cannot be the reason for the speed and memory consumption difference (I also immediately thought of packing as such differences usually happen there, but apparently something else is going on)

Comment: @acl thought about that too. Couldn't check because I'm away from my mma pc. Would unpacking explain the 25 fold increase in memory?

Comment: @Sjoerd well, f = Range[100];Developer`PackedArrayQ[f];ByteCount[f];g = Developer`FromPackedArray[f];Developer`PackedArrayQ[g];ByteCount[g] says 568 and 3240 for the `ByteCount` of the packed and unpacked array, so I guess not. But I am not so familiar with how packing works for multidimensional arrays, so it's possible.

Comment: @acl, I'm not getting a packing message using Total/@pairs using V8.  What version are you using?

Comment: @Joshua 8.0.1 on OS X. Let me try to see what I am doing differently. Also, @Sjoerd, if I check the `ByteCount` for f = Tuples[Range[1000], {2}]; instead, it's 14 times higher with unpacked arrays

Comment: @Joshua: You're right. `Total/@pairs` does not unpack for `pairs` longer than some threshold. If I do `pairs = Tuples[Range[n], {2}];`, they both unpack for n<10, while `Total/@pairs` doesn't unpack for n>10 (but the `Apply` version still does).

Comment: Great! It seems we're getting close to the cause of the problem, though I don't see the need for the unpacking in this case. Any idea how to prevent this from locking up our systems (second question)?

Comment: Come to think about it: since Plus gets it's arguments liberated from the sublists they were in I guess unpacking is a necessity.

Answer (score 4):

The second part of the question is really actual for *Mathematica* users. I already asked related question in the official newsgroup and got the following [answer from John Fultz](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/WiR8FUdf0vo/RQ3Bm-0MORgJ):

> On Thu, 10 Mar 2011 06:12:04 -0500
>   (EST), Alexey Popkov wrote:
>
> > Instead of MemoryConstrained I would prefer to have
> >     'FreeMemoryConstrained'
> >     function to protect from swapping securely...
>
> That's just not how modern operating
>   systems work.  All memory is virtual
>   memory.  Whether it's backed by RAM,
>   disk, or some other storage medium is
>   a detail that the operating system
>   manages, not applications (with the
>   exception of mechanisms like
>   memory-mapped files).  And if an
>   application did have the ability to
>   lock its memory into RAM, it would be
>   quite unfriendly indeed to other
>   applications on the system.
>
> Would you really want an app that
>   insisted on keeping 2 gigabytes of RAM
>   in play for itself (or ten
>   applications that could keep 200
>   megabytes each), even if the
>   application didn't happen to be doing
>   any computation right now and other
>   apps were totally starved for RAM? 
>   This could lead to a total failure of
>   the operating system itself, which is
>   much worse than swapping.
>
> Modern operating systems simply cannot
>   allow apps to behave in that fashion. 
>   If they did, then instead of swap
>   hell, you would end up with routine
>   failures of the entire operating
>   system itself.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> John Fultz

Despite this, I have implemented myself a function which checks the amount of free physical memory about 100 times per second and with a decrease of its volume below some user-defined threshold restarts slave kernel and executes in a new slave MathKernel process user-defined commands.

This function relies on NETLink and currently is implemented only for 32 bit Windows systems. It is not very expensive and does not take considerable additional processor time since it gets memory-related information by a call to `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` function of kernel32.dll which is pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks! I'm on Win7-64 so your function won't work for me, but it may benefit numerous others. Do you have a link to your function? As to John Fulz's answer: the question was not to lock memory but actually the reverse, not allocating more memory than which is physically free. MMA should be able to do that. The size  of free physical memory is visible to the task manager app, so mma should be able to see that too.

Comment: @Sjoerd It is not published yet and in really is a part of much more complicated function which allows to transparently evaluate some code in a slave kernel (which can be of another version of *Mathematica*) having illusion that the `FrontEnd` works directly with that slave kernel. The code of that function is quite large since it includes analysis of `MathLink` packets and comprehensive set of diagnostic messages. I am still in doubts where and how it is better to publish it. And regarding 64 bit systems: I believe that it is probably easy enough to add support of them.